# How to call a singing voice powerful?

Tags: word-choice, english-to-japanese

If I wanted to say "Mika Kobayashi has a powerful singing voice", for example, could I say

> 小林みかさんは力を持つ歌声があります。

Or is there a better way to say it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about using [力強]{ちからづよ}い, as in:

> 小林みかさんは[力強]{ちからづよ}い歌声を持っています。
> 小林みかさんには力強い歌声があります。
> 小林みかさんの歌声は力強いです。

You can use パワフルな, too:

> 小林みかさんはパワフルな歌声を持っています。
> 小林みかさんにはパワフルな歌声があります。
> 小林みかさんの歌声はパワフルです。

Answer (score 2):

Some other choices could be

- 芯{しん}の通{とお}った声{こえ}  - A voice with a core, a firm voice.
- 張{は}りのある声{こえ} - A projecting voice.